# How to check which role has privileges on a table in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I want to get list of all roles which are granted to a table.
From information_schema.table_privileges table, I could get only PUBLIC. But how do I get if any specific role is granted to a table? I tried using information_schema.role_table_grants table also. That is also giving only list of privileges (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, ...) which are granted on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query may help you,

```
SELECT relname, relacl FROM pg_class where relname='table_name';
```

`relacl` column will display the access privileges assigned by `GRANT` and `REVOKE`.

Comment: Always try to upvote if it helps... Its good way to say thanks :)